# Use the same template with different data in meteor.js

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

I have a template displaying a map in my meteor application. This template is used for two things :

- Display the search results of my app on a map
- Display the individual location of a particular venue once the user selected one

Currently my code is the following (I have no other function or helper regarding this template) :

```
Template.map.rendered = function() {
if(!map)
    var map = new Course_map('#map');

Deps.autorun(function(){

    if (Session.get("current_place")){
        var places = Places.find(Session.get("current_place")).fetch();
    }
    else{
        var places_cursor =  get_searched_places();
        if (places_cursor){
            var places = places_cursor[0].fetch();
            var places_id = _.pluck(places,'_id');

            //Remove the markers that are no longer in the places_id array
            map.remove_markers(places_id);
        }
    }

    if(places){
        // Add all the marker in places
        for(var i = 0, places_length = places.length; i < places_length; i ++){
            map.add_marker(places[i]);
        }
        // Recenter the map to focus on the marker area
        map.calc_bounds();
    }
});
};
```

My map template :

```
<template name="map">
<div id="map" class='google-map'>
</div>
```

Depending on whether the user selected a place with Session.get("current_place") I load different information in my places variable.

I don't really like that design and I think I could find a better way to do what I am trying to do. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: @Itbesh Your solution looks fine to me. The only thing I don't like is the definition of the `map` variable. I suppose you need to use `this.map` (or even `this._map`, see [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_inst)) since you definitely want to attatch this object to your template instacne, not to the local scope. Am I right?

Comment: @ Tomasz : Thanks for your comment. I edited my post to show my template and precise that the code for rendered is the only code for this template. So no I don't use this.map I created the map like this because I need a map, how would you do it otherwise ?

Comment: From what you're saying I assume that you need to access this `map` object from somewhere else in your code, so it is probably defined globally, right? Then why you're using `var` prefix? Note that a variable prefixed with `var` will be only defined locally, so your global `map` stays unchanged and the condition `if (!map)` is in fact always satisfied. So in fact you're creating a new instance of `Course_map` on each `render` event, but I assume that's not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one of the problems you're facing is how to integrate Meteor with an external maps API. Although it's tempting to do this imperatively, Meteor actually provides a much easier way to do with the [`cursor#observeChanges()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe) function, of which the `added`, `changed`,  and `removed` callbacks you can just directly hook up to the maps API.

I've actually implemented a mapping application with Meteor and OpenLayers, which does exactly this. Scroll down to the very end:

> https://github.com/mizzao/CrowdMapper/blob/master/client/views/map.coffee